# What does this list create?

Tags: c#, list

I am trying to understand some code we went over today in class where we created a class below,

```
    class Datapoint
    {
        private string latitude;
        private string longtitude;
        private string elevation;

        public Datapoint()
        {
            latitude = "no data";
            longtitude = "no data";
            elevation = "no data";
        }

        public Datapoint(string latitude, string longtitude, string elevation)
        {
            this.latitude = latitude;
            this.longtitude = longtitude;
            this.elevation = elevation;
        }

        public string Latitude { get { return latitude; } }
        public string Longtitude { get { return longtitude; } }
        public string Elevation { get { return elevation; } }
    }
```

and then made a list from this class,

```
List<Datapoint> datapoints;
```

Is this a list that goes

```
latitude 
longtitude
elevation
latitude 
longtitude
elevation
latitude 
longtitude
elevation
latitude 
longtitude
elevation
```

and so on and so forth? Thank you for any help.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking.  The code sample seems quite straightforward.  What, specifically, about the code sample don't you understand?  You clearly talked about it in class, so explaining *everything* about it shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: +1  I don't agree with people downvoting without an explanation.  I think this question was fine -- you explained the problem well and described what you did not understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you are thinking of the `Datapoint` class as *itself* a type of list structure. While you *could* think of it this way, that isn't the way most programmers would visualize it.

An easier entity to understand might be a person. Do you think of a person as a *list*, like this?

- Age
- Gender
- Height
- Weight
- Hair color
- Eye color

...and so on? I think not. A person has many attributes or properties; but if you consider a list of people, this list is not simply a concatenated sequence of person-properties but rather of person entities (or *instances*).

So as others have pointed out, a `List<Datapoint>`, or a list of `Datapoint` objects, is not merely a list of the properties of these objects but in fact a list of the objects themselves (each of which has properties).

---

At a lower level, if you're asking how this information is *stored* then you're actually close. Obviously, for a `Datapoint` object to be allocated in memory, there must be room for all of its properties; and these will most likely be allocated in a contiguous block (though at this point we're getting to a level of implementation detail most developers would argue you shouldn't even be thinking about for purposes of writing software—that's another discussion I'll save for someone else!).

Now, you might think that it would therefore make sense to *store* a list of `Datapoint` objects much like you suggested:

```
latitude  // first object
longitude
elevation
latitude  // second object
longitude
elevation
...       // etc.
```

However, as you may have learned in class already, reference types are not stored in this way in .NET. Given a collection of objects, each instance may be stored anywhere; what you have in a `List<Datapoint>` is actually a bunch of *references* to these objects, in much the same way that if I had this list:

- 123 Main St
- 456 Broad St
- 789 Chestnut St

...the buildings at these addresses would not need to actually reside next to one another.

Hopefully this helps you to understand what a `List<Datapoint>` actually is: a list of references to objects, which have properties but are not traditionally thought of as lists themselves (though in some sense they are), and which may be allocated and exist at non-adjacent points in memory.

Comment: Thank you I just came to this conclusion :]

Answer (score 2):

The list stores `Datapoint` objects. It doesn't have an order of latitude, longitude, elevation, etc. You can get a `Datapoint` object from the list, and then get latitude, longitude, elevation in whatever order you choose like this:

```
Datapoint myPoint = datapoints[0];
Console.WriteLine(myPoint.latitude);
//etc for which ever measurement you want
```

Answer (score 0):

This List will contain a collection of Datapoints. The Datapoints in this collection will contain the public properties Latitude, Longitude and Elevation.

Answer (score 0):

This is a list of your DataPoints object.  So if you wanted to get the properties of each, you would access the object in the list first.  Something like:

```
foreach(DataPoint dp in datapoints)
{
    //do something with dp.Latitude
    //do something with dp.Longitude
    //do something with dp.Elevation
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Datapoint> datapoints;
```

this line initializes the List, but won't actually put items inside of it. You then would need to add items to this list from either your default constructor or custom constructor. Something like this.

```
Datapoint thePointToBeInserted = new Datapoint():   //this will cause it to create a Datapoint where the three properties are "no data".
theListOfDataPoints.Add(thePointToBeInserted);   //we add the object to the list.  
theListofDataPoints.Add(new DataPoint("Example latitude", "etc", "etc"));  //adding with custom constructor.
```